# Check if all "CMD_xxx" are executable using loop

Tags: bash, centos, centos6

How do I check if all variables "CMD_xxx" are executable in bash script?
I can check one by one with `[` or `test` command, but I'd like to know how I check them with loop.

**[Question]** How do I check all variables which start "CMD_" with loop command?

This is my image. (Does not work)

```
for v in ${!CMD_@}
do
  if [ ! -x ${$v}} ]; then 
    echo ${${v}} does not executable.
    exit 1
  fi
done
```

My environment is CentOS6.6 bash 4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how you perform indirection.

```
if [ ! -x "${!v}" ]
```